# Is it possible to transfer a list of Perl installed packages to another machine and mark for installation in ActiveState's ActivePerl?

Tags: perl, package-managers, activestate

So we are migrating servers. Arghh. There is a lot of Perl stuff on one machine that we need to set up on another one.

Is there a way to export / import a list of all packages that are installed so that I can install them on the new server instead of looking up one by one?
(using ActivePerl)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `ppm`, you can use `ppm profile` commands. You can store a list of installed packages via

```
ppm profile save my_modules.xml
```

and restore on another machine with

```
ppm profile restore my_modules.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cpan -a
```

will create a `Bundle` of all your installed packages, which can be moved to your CPAN directory on the other system and installed there.

I did this once, a few years ago, and it seemed to work then.

Comment: Thanks! now i have a bundle. Any idea how to install it now? (we are running Windows Server on the system)

Comment: I think it's the same location that you `cpan` put it in (but on the other system).  Details are hard to provide because they may depend on whose Perl distribution (ActivePerl, Strawberry Perl, Cygwin, etc.) you run and I hardly ever use anything but Cygwin myself.

Comment: Then `ppm` is the first thing to try - as you've acknowledged already.

Comment: Does CPAN really work in ActivePerl (no C compiler available)? Don't they have their own package system ([PPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_package_manager))? From *[Perl package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_package_manager)*: *"PPM is widespread on Microsoft Windows systems, which often lack the C and C++ compilers necessary to build some Perl modules."*

Comment: I suppose CPAN doesn't work well in ActivePerl - I've never really used ActivePerl so I don't really know.